# SQL Server variable in string

Tags: sql

I have stored proc which send string w/quotes works ok:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Proc] @Store char(5)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(Server, 'SELECT * FROM T WHERE Store = ''MA009'' GROUP BY Store')
END
```

How insert @Store in openquery string? below not working

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Proc] @Store char(5)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(Server, 'SELECT * FROM T WHERE Store = '''+ @Store + ''' GROUP BY Store')
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx),

***OPENQUERY does not accept variables for its arguments.***

However, you can try the below;

```
DECLARE @SQL varchar(8000), @Store char(5)
SELECT  @Store = 'MA009'
SELECT  @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MyLinkedServer,''SELECT * FROM T WHERE Store =''''' + @Store + ''''' GROUP BY Store '')'
EXEC   (@SQL)
```

OR you can use the **Sp_executesql** Stored Procedure

To avoid the multi-layered quotes, use code that is similar to the following sample:

```
DECLARE @Store char(5)
SELECT  @Store = 'MA009'
EXEC    MyLinkedServer.master.dbo.sp_executesql
        N'SELECT * FROM T WHERE Store = @var',
        N'@var char(5)',
        @Store
```

Comment: Thanks first example working, but im stuggling with quotes can you help me if additional quotes added?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use variables in **OPENQUERY**. But you can use a variable with following Workaround:

```
DECLARE @test nvarchar(MAX);

SET @test = 'MyStringValue';
DECLARE @query nvarchar(max) = 
    'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(adamm_db,''Select * 
                                        FROM databaseName.schemaName.table 
                                        WHERE id = '''''  + @test  + ''''''')'
EXEC(@query)
```